# daily-19909.cdiff not found on remote server

Tags: command-line, clamav

I have got ClamAV installed. And recently when I have been executing the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo freshclam
```

I have been getting errors such as this one which I got today:

```
ClamAV update process started at Sun Jan 11 20:00:37 2015
main.cvd is up to date (version: 55, sigs: 2424225, f-level: 60, builder: neo)
WARNING: getfile: daily-19909.cdiff not found on remote server (IP: 150.214.142.197)
WARNING: getpatch: Can't download daily-19909.cdiff from db.local.clamav.net
WARNING: getfile: daily-19909.cdiff not found on remote server (IP: 209.198.147.20)
WARNING: getpatch: Can't download daily-19909.cdiff from db.local.clamav.net
Trying host db.local.clamav.net (200.236.31.1)...
Downloading daily-19909.cdiff [100%]
daily.cld updated (version: 19909, sigs: 1306781, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 245, sigs: 43, f-level: 63, builder: dgoddard)
Database updated (3731049 signatures) from db.local.clamav.net (IP: 200.236.31.1)
```

Why is this happening? And why does it happen so much now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered in the ClamAV FAQs section here: http://www.clamav.net/doc/mirrors-faq.html

Information from FAQs section on this:

```
ERROR: getfile: daily-*.cdiff not found on remote server
For some reason, the mirror didn’t fetch the cdiff file. Freshclam can recover from this situation by trying the next mirror.
```